# how to replace or eliminate @xsi::nill => true in php multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array like this

```
print_r(myarray) is

Array ( [0] => Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true ) [1] => Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true ) [2] => Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true ) [3] => 'some value' [4] => Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true ))
```

I need to eliminate the values `Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true )` or just to replace them with say `"nill"`. I tried a lot, this being a nested array i couldnt get the key for the values `[@xsi:nil] => true`

How to check in php for the indexes which hold the value `Array ( [@xsi:nil] => true )`? and replace them with say 'nill'?

trial one :

```
$key1 = array_search(array('@xsi:nil'=>'true'), array_column($arrays, 'NOTE')); //to catch the indexes.

function searchMyCoolArray($arrays, $key, $search) {
                       $count = 0;

                       foreach($arrays as $object) {
                           if(is_object($object)) {
                               $ob1 = $object;
                              $object = get_object_vars($object);

                              $key1 = array_search(40489, array_column($arrays, 'uid'));
                           }

                           if(array_key_exists($key, $object) && $object[$key] == $search)
                           {
                              // print_r($first_names_note[$key]);
                              // echo "ffgfg  ".$ob1[0]."  rtrtrt";
                             // var_dump($object);
                            // print_r($arrays[$key]);
                              // echo $object;
                             // print_r($object);
                               // print_r($first_names_note)."<br>";
                               $count++;

                               //echo "sddsdsdsd";

                           }
                       }

                       return $count;
                    } 

 echo searchMyCoolArray($first_names_note, '@xsi:nil', 'true');

  here i got the count correct, but it was not i need, I tried to get the indexs in the function itself, but failed
```

Please help, i googled alot pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeez

Comment: Will this `some value` always be a string or can they be array as well ?

Comment: it will always be a string

Comment: _i tried a lot_? and where are your trials? isn't this just using an `if`

Comment: should `[@xsi:nil] => false` remain as is?

Comment: So why cant you just loop over it and replace the value with null if its an array ?? only if the array is two level deep as you have shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use `array_walk` to traverse the array and then unset all elements with the key `@xsi:nil` like this:

```
    <?php

        $arr   = array(
            array("@xsi:nil" => true),
            array("@xsi:nil" => true),
            array("@xsi:nil" => true),
            array("some_value" =>4),
            array("@xsi:nil" => true),
        );

        array_walk($arr, function(&$data){
            if(is_array($data) && array_key_exists("@xsi:nil", $data)){
                unset($data["@xsi:nil"]);
                $data[] = "nil";
            }
        });

        var_dump($arr);

        // IF YOU WANT TO REMOVE ALL EMPTY ARRAYS COMPLETELY, JUST DO THIS:
        $arr   = array_filter($arr);

        var_dump($arr);

        // GET THE LENGTH OF THE FILTERED ARRAY.
        $count = count($arr);  
        echo $count;   //<== PRODUCES 5

        // THE 1ST VAR_DUMP() PRODUCES:         
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              'some_value' => int 4
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)

        // THE 2ND VAR_DUMP() PRODUCES:
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              'some_value' => int 4
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'nil' (length=3)
```

Test it out [HERE](https://eval.in/608389).

Cheers & Good Luck...

Comment: i dont need to unset, i just need to replace it with nill, if unset it i get result as `[0] => Array ( )` i need [0] => as 'nill'

Comment: @Mukund     You can still `unset` and then add the `nil` in place. The Updated Code shows how....

Comment: Thaaaaank you vey much

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer, the code for the answer was provided  by @Poiz

Here is my complete code which i formatted

```
//my array
 $arr = Array (Array ( '@xsi:nil' => 'true' ), Array ('@xsi:nil' => 'true' ), Array ( '@xsi:nil' => 'true' ) );

      //  print_r($arr);
//performed array walk
        array_walk($arr, function(&$data){
            if(is_array($data) && array_key_exists("@xsi:nil", $data)){
               unset($data["@xsi:nil"]);
               $data = "nil";
            }
        });


        print_r($arr);
//OUTPUT : Array ( [0] => nil [1] => nil [2] => nil )
```

Comment: Sincerity and Honesty goes a long, long way.... that is a Great Asset so keep it up....